# How to check if free(node) works

Tags: c, linked-list, free

Here is the code for freeing the whole linked list

```
void free_list(RecordType *list)
{
   RecordType *tempNode;        /* temporary Node to hold on the value of previous node */

   while(list != NULL)          /* as long as the listnode doesn't point to null */
   {
       tempNode = list;         /* let tempNode be listNode in order to free the node */
       list = list->next;       /* let list be the next list (iteration) */
       free(tempNode);          /* free the node! */
   }
}
```

I think this code itself is working ok (?), but I have no idea how to check.
I only applied the theory (e.g. # of frees must = to the # of mallocs)

So here are some questions that I'm wondering...

1. Does this method work?
2. Do I need to malloc tempNode?
3. I initialized tempNode before while loop... but after I free, tempNode still works... I don't really get that part

The theory that I used:

1. # of free() == # of malloc()
2. You need a temporary node to hold the current node
3. Let the current node equal to the next node
4. Free the current node by using the temporary node

If any of my theory sounds wrong, please explain!

Thanks!

Comment: Its working, assuming you did, in fact, build your list correctly (and it looks like you probably did). Your theory-list is spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method certainly works - but it should be `malloc`d first before `free`ing. Otherwise it is undefined behavior.

You don't need to `malloc()` `tempNode` only if `list` has been previously `malloc()`d.

The third part is undefined behavior. After `free()` the data may still exist, but is flagged for being overwritten. You cannot rely on the node once it is `free()`d

Comment: So if I used an insert first method correctly to make the list with using malloc, I need to malloc tempNode?

Comment: @LarsChung no you don't. Infact, if you do that and then say `tempNode = list; ` then youu will be leaking memory here. When you type the line `tempNode = list; ` you are essentially pointing `tempNode` at whatever `list` points to(which is hopefully `malloc()`d)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this method work?

Yes, assuming the list nodes were all dynamically allocated and haven't been previously freed

> Do I need to malloc tempNode?

You don't need to allocate any memory inside `free_list` but all list elements must have been dynamically allocated previously.  You can only call `free` on memory that was allocated using `malloc` (or `calloc`)

> I initialized tempNode before while loop... but after I free, tempNode
>   still works... I don't really get that part

Calling `free` returns ownership of memory to the system.  It may choose to reuse this memory immediately or may leave it untouched for some time.  There's nothing to stop you accessing the memory again but the results of reading or writing it are undefined.

If you want to make it harder for client code to accidentally access freed memory, you could change `free_list` to NULL their pointer

```
void free_list(RecordType **list)
{
    RecordType *tempNode;
    while(*list != NULL) {
        tempNode = *list;
        list = tempNode->next;
        free(tempNode);
    }
    *list = NULL;
}
```

If you also want to check that you really have freed all memory, look into using valgrind.  This will report any memory leaks and also flags some types of invalid memory access.

Comment: +1, though I think his question about `tempNode` was specific to the nature of his loop. What `tempNode` *points* to obviously better have been properly allocated (or NULL) or this is UB, but in the context of `free_list()` no `malloc()` *calls* should be needed. And just because I sometimes like making my co-workers [scratch their heads](http://ideone.com/rIyqjD) (note the `free()` call =P)

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right that I mis-interpreted that part of the question.  I've updated that bit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check your code is interactive tracing by means of Debugger. Gdb in KDevelop on Linux or MS Visual Studio's debugger on MS Windows are perfect. I'll use the later for this demonstration.

This code defines a uni-directed list of integers with three functions: ListPush() adds an integer to the list, ListPrint() displays the list contents and ListDestroy() destroys the list. In main() I insert 3 integers into the list, print them and destroy the list.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Node NODE, *PNODE;
typedef struct Node {
    int item;
    PNODE next;
};
PNODE ListPush(PNODE head, int item) {
    PNODE p;
    PNODE n = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if ( !n ) exit(1);
    n->next = 0;
    n->item = item;

    if (!head) {
        head = n;
    }
    else {
        for ( p=head; p->next != 0; p=p->next );
        p->next = n;    
    }
    return head;
}

void ListPrint(PNODE head) {
    PNODE p;
    printf("List contents:\n\n");
    for (p=head; p!=0; p=p->next) {
        printf("%d ", p->item ); 
    }
}

void ListDestroy( PNODE head ) {
    PNODE n, c = head;
    if ( !head ) return; 
    do {
        n = c->next;
        free(c);
        c = n;
    } while (c );

}

int main() {
    int i;
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    PNODE head = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i<3; ++i ) {
        head = ListPush(head, a[i]);
    }
    ListPrint(head);
    ListDestroy(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Three attached images illustrate 2 stages of the program (MSVS2012 Debugger).

The first shows state of relevant local vars after for() cycle finishes. Look at head variable and proceed on the tree. You can see three nodes with their contents: integers 1,2 and 3 respectively.

The second image shows the variables inside ListDestroy() after first call to free(). You can see that head points to freed memory (red circles) and pointer in variable c points to the next node being destroyed on the next loop.

[image: After 3 pushes]

[image: After first call to free()]